# gridview updating/inserting the columns

Tags: c#, asp.net

am editing and updateing the gridview columns but it not taking the values. and it not show the error.

plz tell the suggestion. how to do the updated. if am click on edit it enable. when am enter the values it not updating the db.

```
if (ViewState["LeaveManagementID"] == null)

        {

                foreach (GridViewRow row in gvLeaves.Rows)
                {

                    EP_LeaveManagementRow leaveUpdateRow = db.EP_LeaveManagementCollection.GetRow("LeaveManagementID=" + gvLeaves.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);

                    if (leaveUpdateRow != null)
                    {
                        leaveUpdateRow.NoOfDays = int.Parse(lblNoOfDays.Text.ToString());


                        db.EP_LeaveManagementCollection.Update(leaveUpdateRow);
                        ViewState["LeaveManagementID"] = leaveUpdateRow.LeaveManagementID;

                        mvLeaveManagement.SetActiveView(vwLeavesDetails);
```

ASPX

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comments">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="15%" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle"></HeaderStyle>
                                             <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Label ID="lblComments" Visible="false" runat="server" ></asp:Label>

                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" MaxLength="50" TextMode="MultiLine"  Text='<%#Bind("LeaveCommants") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                            </EditItemTemplate>

                                        </asp:TemplateField>


 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit/Update" HeaderStyle-Width="25%">
                                                <ItemTemplate>

                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lkbEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit"  />
                                                    <%-- <asp:LinkButton ID="lkbUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update"  />--%>


                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                               <EditItemTemplate>

                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />

                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: lots of example you can find on google this is one of them http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/02/how-to-inserteditupdate-and-delete-data.html

Comment: here is your solution if you want to insert delete and update a data into a database using GridView follow this link:-http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/05/gridview-sqldatasource-insert-edit.html